# A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction() - but only in controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jta

I am trying to use a Spring Data JPA repository to get and persist entities. When I use this repository from within a e.g. a Quartz job, everything works perfectly. When I try to use this repo from within a RestController, I get the following error message: "A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()". Of course I googled for a solution, but it seems that my case is a bit different than the cases that I have found. Any ideas what might cause this kind of error?

Example of Service class using this repo:

```
@Service
public class ServiceToTablesMappingServiceImpl implements ServiceToTablesMappingService {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceToTablesMappingRepository repo;

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void createMapping(String serviceName, Set<String> tables) {

    for (String table : tables) {
      ServiceToTablesMappingEntity entity = new ServiceToTablesMappingEntity();
      entity.setServiceName(serviceName);
      entity.setTableName(table);
      this.repo.save(entity); //this line causes the error
    }
  }
...
```

Code of my repo:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import xxx.ServiceToTablesMappingEntity;

@Repository
public interface ServiceToTablesMappingRepository extends CrudRepository<ServiceToTablesMappingEntity, Long> {

  @Transactional
  List<ServiceToTablesMappingEntity> findByServiceName(String serviceName);
}
```

Code of Controller:

```
@RestController
public class InitialLoadController {
  ...  
  @Autowired
  private ServiceToTablesMappingService regService;

  /**
   * Triggers the initial load workflow preparation
   *
   * @param service The service which tries to prepare
   * @param request The request which contains a list of tables along with some other information about the subscriber
   * @return Return the 200 status code if everything went fine
   */
  @PostMapping("/init-prepare")
  public ResponseEntity<Void> initPrepare(@RequestBody InitialLoadRequestDto request) {

    // create mapping
    Set<String> tables = request.getTables();
    String service = request.getServiceName();
    this.regService.createMapping(service, tables);

   ...

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
...
```

And here´s how I configure the entityManager:

```
@Configuration
@DependsOn("transactionManager")
@ComponentScan({ "xxx", "yyy" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "xxx",
"yyy" }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "datasupplyEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager", queryLookupStrategy = Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DbDatasourceProperties.class)
public class DatasupplyConfig {
...
@Bean(name = "datasupplyEntityManager")
  @DependsOn("jpaVendorAdapter")
  @Autowired
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter,
      DataSource xaDataSource) {

    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", AtomikosJtaPlatform.class.getName());
    properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "JTA");
    properties.put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", this.useJdbcMetadataDefaults);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerBean.setDataSource(xaDataSource);
    entityManagerBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    entityManagerBean.setPackagesToScan("xxx",
        "yyyy");
    entityManagerBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return entityManagerBean;
  }
...
```

Comment: Try `entityManagerBean.setJtaDataSource(xaDataSource)` instead of `entityManagerBean.setDataSource(xaDataSource)` (assuming you have a JTA transaction manager configured properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it took me a while to answer. I have found the issue. The issue was indeed what https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126526/manish suggested: I had to change the dataSource to a jtaDataSource. I don´t know, why I didn´t see that before.